# Detect if device is accessed using VNC

Tags: vnc, c, vncserver, realvnc, vnc-viewer

I like to check if our application on remote host is being accessed via VNC Viewer or other similar product of VNC. There are security preferences in our application which should restrict access to the application if being accessed by a remote user.

Traditionally, our product detects remote login by using [Windows Terminal Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/)(WTS) API but VNC doesn't look like following Window's Remote Desktop Protocol. Hence, our application doesn't get the information of remote user logged-in from WTS API.

Is there any API to detect the VNC remote session on the end host ?

Comment: Programming questions are off topic here and belong on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You're right that VNC does not integrate with Terminal Services – the way it works is by capturing the contents of the display much like a screenshot tool, and by sending fake keyboard/mouse events. Because of this, the session is simultaneously local *and* remote (i.e. it remains locally attached in WTS even while it's remotely controlled).

You can (probably) distinguish the input events from real ones (and if it's for "security purposes" then that's probably the part you want to focus on, anyway), but you cannot detect the presence of the actual connection as each remote access tool does it differently and there's no common API they use. (Don't forget that there are multiple independent VNC apps, and then there's TeamViewer and AnyDesk and PiKVM and...)

---

Having just recently needed to walk around a whole lab to manually install X copies of a program which absolutely refused to allow an academic license to be activated through Remote Desktop, I would like to express my disapproval of such "features".

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, it is a popular security preference used by our customers and have to find a solution.